# when I click view button in CGridView, it is opened in a new window

Tags: php, yii, target, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I used from CGridView in framework Yii, I want when I click view button , it is opened in a new window
how can I add  of "_new" of  target ?

Comment: what have you tried. See this link : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `'options' => array('target'=>'_new')` to CButtonColumn configuration array in CGridView

```
array(
    'class'=>'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{view}',
    'buttons'=>array(
        'view' => array(
            'url' => '', // view url
            'options' => array('target' => '_new'),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the html properties by using 'options' property.

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => array(
            'table_field_1',
            'table_field_2',
            'table_field_3',
            array(
                'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                /* ===== Template to set the buutons. Ex: If you dont want delete link, remove {delete} */
                //'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array(
                        'options' => array('class' => 'newWindow'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

But, Opening a new window is browser dependent. With `target="_blank"` and `target="_new"` link will be opened in new tab in Mozilla, But in IE you will get new window. So user javascript to generate new window.

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => array(
            'table_field_1',
            'table_field_2',
            'table_field_3',
            array(
                'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                /* ===== Template to set the buutons. Ex: If you dont want delete link, remove {delete} */
                //'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array(
                        'options' => array('class' => 'newWindow'),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

Keep this jQuery in your .js file

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".newWindow").click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url=$(this).attr('href');
                window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=100, width=1020, height=500");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'table_field_1',
        'table_field_2',
        'table_field_3',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            /* ===== Template to set the buutons. Ex: If you dont want delete link, remove {delete} */
            //'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'view' => array(
                    'options' => array('target' => '_blank'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```